# Change the exported function name of a compiled shared library

Tags: android, shared-libraries, egl, name-mangling

Long story short: I have a compiled shared library where the source code is not available and it has the name of an important function (C++) mangled.

Is it possible to patch this binary somehow such that the exported name is not mangled?
I know `patchelf` can modify the dependencies, but I don't know how to modify the symbols.

Longer: I have a libEGL.so from a phone which has e.g. `_Z14eglCreateImagePvS_jS_PKi` instead of `eglCreateImage` which causes the EGL-Loader to not find it (via `dlsym`) because it (of course) searches only for the non-mangled names.

Strangely all other APIs (except for 6) are exported without mangling, so I expect this to be a bug on their side.

Patching the loader to consider mangled names is possible but also a lot of work, so I'd rather change or add the correct names to the binary.

Answer (score 2):

If the loader uses `dlsym` with `RTLD_DEFAULT` you could introduce a weak alias introduce into your main program. In case there's the proper function available, that weak alias will be ignored. Compile with a C compiler (not C++):

```
// egl_mangle_wrapper.c
EGLImage eglwrap_CreateImage(
    EGLDisplay dpy,
    EGLContext ctx,
    EGLenum tgt,
    EGLClientBuffer buf,
    const EGLAttrib *atrl )
{
    return _Z14eglCreateImagePvS_jS_PKi(dpy, ctx, tgt, buf, atrl);
}

EGLImage eglCreateImage(
    EGLDisplay dpy,
    EGLContext ctx,
    EGLenum tgt,
    EGLClientBuffer buf,
    const EGLAttrib *atrl )
        __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("eglwrap_CreateImage")));
```

Comment: This seems to be loaded with `RTLD_NOW | RTLD_LOCAL`, so I guess this won't work. I also need to mention  that I don't really have a "main program" but am just updating a Custom ROM. Hence I'd prefer to modify that "faulty" binary.

Comment: Pathching the mangled name will probably break a lot of things. Your best course of action is to somehow introduce a weak alias. I'll have to think about that, I can can come up with a solution…

Comment: "Pathching the mangled name will probably break a lot of things" -- in particular, it will break the symbol hash table, so the patched symbol will never be found.

Answer (score 0):

The ability to do this was added in Patchelf: https://github.com/NixOS/patchelf/commit/da035d6acee1e5a608aafe5f6572a67609b0198a

It should be available in the next release (after 0.17.2). Meanwhile you can build the tool following the instructions in https://github.com/NixOS/patchelf#compiling-and-testing

To use it, create a map file with two names (old and new) per line, and invoke Patchelf with:

```
$ patchelf --output libPatched.so --rename-dynamic-symbols map_file libOriginal.so
```

Please provide feedback if you find issues. Thanks!